# Reverse a tree structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a tree structure and I am using jstree jquery plugin to it.

I basically want to reverse the structure.  [image]

The structure should look something like this. I have edited this in MS word so it doesnot have the folder view as in the first image. Basically the first element should be "Friend" only but it must start from the bottom. Please change abs to abc.
Please help me with it. Thanks in advance

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='..../jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='.../jstree.min.js'></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href='...../style.min.css' />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="..../jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="tree.js"></script>

    <head>
      <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
      <title>Insert title here</title>
     </head>

     <body>
       <button id="idClickMe">Click me</button>
       <div id='jstree'>
       </div>
     </body>
  </html>
```

js Code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 

   $('#idClickMe').click(function(){ 
     var resultant="<ul><li data-jstree='{'selected' : true, 'opened' : true }><span>Friend</span><ul><li>abc</li></ul></li><li><span>Wife</span></li><li><span>Company</span></li></ul>";
     $("#jstree").jstree('destroy').html(resultant);
     $("#jstree").jstree(); 

     //$("#jstree").jstree("refresh");
   }); 
 });
```

Comment: Why can't you switch the positions in your html string?

Comment: It will be difficult as the hierarchy increases . Also the structure is dynamic. I want a parent -child structure and a child -parent structure. Hence I need to reverse the earlier structure.

Comment: Well there is nothing dynamic shown in the question code so we have no idea how it gets created. Please edit question and include all relevant code and information

Comment: if you get your informations from a database put the items in an array and use array reverse

Answer (score 0):

i see u use html for that so maybe this reverse snipped of html ll help u:

```
$top = $('div#thatTopDiv');
$top.children('div').slice(1).each(function() {
    $(this).insertBefore($top.children().eq(0));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If noting help : Turn upside-down DIV tree and turn upside-down text on each leaf of the tree.

css:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Comment: Thanks everyone... @pavel I tried doing the upside down  and it actually reverted the structure . Exactly the way I wanted. From the diagram "Company" appeared in the top and "Friend" in the bottom. However the alphabets are also inverted now. Is there a CSS way to invert the particular values.?? Thanks for the help

Comment: I used this code to inverse the structure: -moz-transform: scale(1,-1);
              -o-transform: scale(1,-1);
              -webkit-transform: scale(1,-1);
              transform:scale(1,-1);

Comment: I'm happy that I helped. If you do not have it yet solved, insert text into the span ( or div display: inline ) and set his class that upsite-down text -> turns text back like double half rotation. Include text like `var leaf = '<span class="HalfRotation">Friends</span>';` instead of `var leaf = 'Friends';`

Comment: Hey Pavel Thanks a ton Man... It worked.. Exact structure with exact element. Basically I added this line .<span style='-ms-transform:rotateX(-180deg)'>" + localRowID + "</span>". Secondly to the html file i added these lines.              .#treeViewOfWhereUsed {

-moz-transform: scale(1,-1);
              -o-transform: scale(1,-1);
              -webkit-transform: scale(1,-1);
              transform:scale(1,-1);
}     Thanks everyone...